# Trying to clean up boundaries on nearest neighbour plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

I'm doing a small plot with some training data before testing it in python. My plot looks like this right now. The training data comes from images of letters in Fourier space which I have masked to produce different values for the letters.

[image]

These boundaries look less than ideal to me and I'm not sure how to go about fixing them so that red and blue points have there own distinct areas. Here is the code I am using:

```
X = np.matrix(X)
#knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
y = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]

h = 0.2  # step size in the mesh


# Create color maps
cmap_light = ListedColormap(['#FFAAAA', '#AAFFAA', '#AAAAFF'])
cmap_bold = ListedColormap(['#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#0000FF'])

n_neighbors = 10
for weights in ['uniform', 'distance']:
    # we create an instance of Neighbours Classifier and fit the data.
    clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors, weights=weights)
    clf.fit(X, y)


    # Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
    # point in the mesh [x_min, x_max]x[y_min, y_max].
    x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 30, X[:, 0].max() + 20
    y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 5, X[:, 1].max() + 5
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                         np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
    Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

    # Put the result into a color plot
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    plt.figure()
    plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, cmap=cmap_light)

    # Plot also the training points

    plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap=cmap_bold)
    plt.xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
    plt.ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
    plt.title("3-Class classification (k = %i, weights = '%s')"
              % (n_neighbors, weights))

plt.show()
```

Is it a case of finding different data points to classify my data with? Or is there a way of changing how these decision boundaries are formed? Any help would be appreciated, please let me know if I'm being too vague on something. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think matplotlib is just plotting what it's been asked to plot. So I tagged the question with the scikit-learn tag.